# How would the Imperial Player use the scouted card? (Imperial Assault: Jabba's Realm)

Tags: star-wars-imperial-assault

In the Jabba's Realm expansion to Imperial Assault, the Imperial player can get the Scouted upgrade:

> Exhaust this card while a hero with a Bounty token is attacking to reroll 1 defense dice. If you do convert all [complete miss] results to [cancel surge] results.

[Card image at BGG.](https://boardgamegeek.com/image/3189098/star-wars-imperial-assault-jabbas-realm)

I don't see how this would be a benefit to substitute the best defense dice roll with an OK one. How can the Imperial Player use this card to their advantage?

Comment: I'm not certain (thus not an answer), but I think the intent is to allow a reroll for a defense die, but not allow the reroll to result in a [complete miss] result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It lets the Imperial player re-roll a defense die. As a cost/balance for this benefit (in addition to the exhaust), if a Dodge is rolled, the player can't keep it. (It is changed into a weaker, but still okay, evade.)

So it let's you have a re-roll, but a little weaker one than usual—if it's a white die. If it's a black die the Imperial defensive player is re-rolling, this additional cost wouldn't come into play. (Just the exhaust cost in this second case.)

I think the confusion might be coming in if you think you have a choice on whether or not to apply the Dodge to Evade after the re-roll, which is incorrect. *If* you re-roll, you must apply the conversion to the result (when applicable).